# How to inherits a BaseRazorPage in Razor page

Tags: razor-pages

In razor engine way, I can define a BaseRazorPage for all razor views

```
public abstract class BaseRazorPage<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
{
   protected BaseRazorPage()
   {
   }

   protected virtual string L(string name)
   {
     return XXX.Localization.L.Text[name];
   }
......
}
```

Use it in _viewImports.cshtml

```
@inherits BaseRazorPage<TModel>
```

Then I can use the L function to do mutiple language in views:

```
@L("Hello word!")
```

How can I implement same function in Razor page way? Or is there an alternative way to do this?

The razor page can't inherits any class.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use a partial view,and share different languages in each view.

Comment: I have many functions just like L function in the BaseRazorPage.cs, so it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to create an extension for the PageModel class.

```
public static class PageModelExtensions
{
    public static string L(this PageModel pageModel, string name)
    {
        // return a new value. put your logic here
        return name + "_result";
    }
}
```

Now we can use the L method as a member function.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        string value = this.L("test");
    }
}
```

Or we can use the L method in the view like this

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>@Model.L("test")</p>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

If you want to have a base class with your common methods the  following example is what you want.

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{
    public string L(string name)
    {
        return "sample";
    }
}
```

And your razor page class will look like this.

```
public class IndexModel : MyPageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        string value = this.L("test");
    }
}
```

In case you want to inject an object in your base class then you base class should look like this.

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;
    public MyPageModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    public string L(string name)
    {
        return "sample";
    }
}
```

And the Razor page will look like this

```
public class IndexModel : MyPageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        string value = this.L("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't set a base class for Razor Page, this should be a compromise.